# .before() behaviour without DOM

Tags: jquery

```
var a = $('<div id="a" />');
a.before($('<div id="b" />'));
console.log(a);
```

Why do I see the `[<div id=​"a">​</div>​]` as a result and not `[<div id=​"b">​</div>​,<div id=​"a">​</div>​]`?

And how to get the expected result (2 objects) in `a` variable?

[Sample on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pYDAW/)

**UPD**:

I **already** have `a` so I need to modify it. `var a = $('<div id="b" /><div id="a" />');` unfortunately is not a solution

**UPD 2**:

The sample code above is oversimplified (in comparison to real life application), so in real project it is possible case that both elements don't have `id` or any other attribute I can sort by :-(

Comment: What is it you are using this for?

Comment: @James Montagne: It is a widgets library. One widget implements some sort of decorator and need to return the input (the widget passed by parameter) with something prepended.

Comment: It appears that `a.add(a.prev()).toArray().reverse()` is approximately three to four times faster than `a.wrap('<div />').parent().prepend('<div id="b" />').children().unwrap()`. Here is a JSPerf to show the performance difference: http://jsperf.com/jquery-add-array-reverse-vs-wrap-unwrap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because `a` contains only one element(`a`). If you want the expected result try this

```
var a = $('<div id="a" />');
a.before($('<div id="b" />'));
console.log(a.add(a.prev()).toArray().reverse());
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H4MfU/1/)**

Comment: How does that work? how can you append something before a fragment that doesn't exist in the DOM, and then get the element before it?

Comment: I know it does work.. but how? How can you prepend something before an element that doesn't have a parent? I'm wondering how it actually works, maybe I just don't fully understand document fragments. I was refering to ShankarSangoli

Comment: @zerkms - Did you check my answer or the demo?

Comment: Well, I admit it does work, but the code is just terrible. Let's wait for alternatives, and if nothing appears - I'll check this answer

Comment: @ShankarSangoli: yes, I checked and I confirm it works, but code looks to unreadable to accept it right now. I'd wait a little more for better answer. Will check a little later if nothing better will come

Comment: @Kevin - `jQuery` adds it into document fragment until we force it to add into document body.

Comment: Ah, i understand now. a is part of a document fragment, and when you append something before a, you are appending it before a in the document fragment. This can be illustrated by `console.log(a.before('<div id="b" />')[0].parentNode.childNodes);`

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = $('<div id="a" />');
var b = $('<div id="b" />');
a.before(b);
console.log(b.add(a));
```

[**Live example**](http://jsfiddle.net/pYDAW/3/)

Comment: As I stated in the question - I need both, not just newly created

Comment: @zerkms I've updated my answer, but it's still not clear exactly why you're doing this so it might not satisfy you

Comment: I've added 2 updates to the question and answered one comment to the question - it should make things more clear, sorry for being too abstract :-)

Comment: yes, I did ;-) +1 for it but let's wait for more obvious code `a.prev().add(a)` -- this just makes me crazy :-S

Comment: jQuery also has the `.andSelf()` function: `console.log(a.prev().andSelf());`

Comment: @zerkms I've edited to make it as clean as I could. Keep in mind that what you're asking for is not orthodox, and will have to rely on `.add`.

Comment: You don't need the `a.before(b);` line, it doesn't get used. Here is an updated version of your demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pYDAW/4/

Comment: +1, FWIW this is the fastest method by far: http://jsperf.com/jquery-add-array-reverse-vs-wrap-unwrap

Answer (score 2):

To add elements to the stack, use the .add method

```
a.add('<div id="b" />');
```

However, now they are out of order. To fix that, you can use the .sort() method.

```
a.sort(function(a,b){
  return a.id > b.id ? 1 : -1; // reverse 1 and -1 to reverse order
}
```

**Also, since you aren't working in the dom, appending something before a fragment shouldn't actually do anything**.

**Edit:**
Here is an alternative to using `toArray` and `.reverse` in ShankarSangoli's answer.

```
var a = $('<div id="a" />');
a.before($('<div id="b" />'));
a = $(a[0].parentNode.childNodes);
```

Thanks ShankarSangoli.

Comment: I gave the `id` just for the sample and to give the idea of order. In real it is possible that there is even no `id` or any other field I can use to sort by

Comment: I suggest going with ShankarSangoli's answer, it is clean code. I'm not sure what makes you say it is terrible code.

Comment: I'm not sure that some one who sees this `a.add(a.prev()).toArray().reverse()` for the first time will understand that all this magic is done to just put the element before `a`. From my perspective it is not obvious at all. But yes, most likely I'll choose it

Comment: There's nothing wrong with placing a comment before that line explaining what it does since it may not be obvious.

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = $('<div id="b" /><div id="a" />');
```

Will that syntax do it for ya?

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AfHWD/

**UPDATE**

How about wrapping your first element in a container, prepending to it, then removing the wrap:

```
//we start with the initial element
var a = $('<div id="a" />'),

    //we then wrap it in a div, select that div, then prepend the new element, then we can select the children and remove the temporary wrapper
    b = a.wrap('<div />').parent().prepend('<div id="b" />').children().unwrap();
```

`b` now contains the following:

```
<div id="b"></div><div id="a"></div>
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AfHWD/1/

Comment: It is my fault that I haven't specified that I already have `a` and I need to modify it to get the desired results

Comment: @zerkms You can also `wrap` your initial element, `prepend` to the new parent element, then remove the wrapper. See my answer for the **updated** code. ( Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/AfHWD/1/ )

Comment: yep, I also thought about that but expected that there is something I just missed with simply using `before()`